# I have updated app to angular 13, "ngx-popover" library causing to "Ivy" related error while npm start

Tags: angular, angularjs

**I have updated app to angular 13, "ngx-popover" library causing to "Ivy" related error while npm start.**

In "package.json":

```
"ngx-popover": "^0.0.16"
```

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
```

Error while "npm start":

```
Error: node_modules/ngx-popover/index.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (ngx-popover) which declares PopoverModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

"ngx-popover" library is not updated from time. So it may not supporting Angular 13 Ivy.

Please suggest me solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ngx-popover ist definitly not meant to be used by ivy. A simple workaround is using ng-bootstrap and implement their popover:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap